# Text flowing out in two column format due to section title

Tags: formatting, two-column, document-classes

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[sttt]{svjour}

\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Title}

\author{Author}
%
%
\institute{Institute}
%
\date{Received: date / Revised version: date}

\maketitle
%
\begin{abstract}
Channels used for communication in distributed systems Channels used for communication in distributed systems 
Channels used for communication in distributed systems 
Channels used for communication in distributed systems 
Channels used for communication in distributed systems 
Channels used for communication in distributed systems 

\end{abstract}
%
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide a link to your class file. Try setting `\tolerance` to a lower value.

Comment: Can you try `\sloppy`, it might help you.

Comment: \sloppy is not working.

Answer (score 1):

TeX's paragraph setter is good but it's not magical; what it has produced here is the least bad way of setting the particular artificial paragraph you have given it.  With the parameters set in your document class file, the paragraph setter has decided that leaving "distributed" sticking out into the margin is less bad than some other option.

If you replace your dummy text with your real abstract paragraph you may simply find that the problem goes away, because the paragraph setter is better at dealing with real text than dummy text with no periods.

Assuming, however that it remains a problem with your real text, there are several strategies to try besides altering the value of `\tolerance` as suggested in the comments.

1. Ensure you have the correct language and hyphenation rules set.
2. Add a list of allowed hyphenation points in your preamble: eg `\hyphenation{dis-trib-uted}`.
3. Manually add optional hyphens to the troublesome word at the troublesome point, eg `dis\-tri\-buted`.
4. Switch to ragged right formatting for the troublesome paragraphs --- this would look weird in the middle of a document, but might be ok in the abstract.  Use `\raggedright` or better still, load the `ragged2e` package and use `\RaggedRight`.
5. Switch to a smaller font for the troublesome paragraphs --- again this might be ok in the abstract.  Try using `\small`.
6. Rewrite the text to avoid the problem.